# Fade (transition effect) on Swift image button

Tags: ios, image, swift, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` with a Default State and a Highlighted State, so when it is in default state it shows `image.png`, and when is clicked it shows `imageOn.png`.

The only thing that changes between this to images is the background color.

The thing I haven't be able to do is to make a fade between this two images when the button is clicked, to make a fancy background color change. I'm using Swift.

Answer (score 3):

Well i dont have time to test this right now, but i think you code should look something like this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

let normalImage = UIImage(named: "image.png") as UIImage!
let selectedImage = UIImage(named: "imageOn.png") as UIImage!

var mybutton:UIButton  = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton

mybutton.setTitle("Your title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
mybutton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)

self.view.addSubview(button as UIView)
//set normal image 
mybutton.setImage(normalImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
//set highlighted image 
mybutton.setImage(selectedImage, forState: UIControlState.Selected)

mybutton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

}

func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton)
{

if (sender.selected)  { 
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, animations: {
        self.normalImage.alpha = 1.0
        self.selectedImage.alpha = 0.0
    sender.selected = !sender.selected; 
}
else{  
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, animations: {
        self.normalImage.alpha = 0.0
        self.selectedImage.alpha = 1.0  
}

}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering.
Sorry, I think I didn't explained well what I want to do. I need that while the button is clicked, it shows imageOn.png, and when the button is released it goes back to image.png

Comment: I understand! Edited my answer. Try this one out.

Comment: Thanks again for answering!
Are you sure the @selector works in Swift? It's not working on my project, and searching for it in google it seems like is only valid for Object-C. Thanks for your help.